# How to get the user's logs folder in cocoa (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains possibly)

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I'm porting a Carbon application to Cocoa and am looking for the equivalent of `kLogsFolderType` in Cocoa, which currently would return `/Users/me/Library/Logs`

I have seen `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` with the associated types, but can't find a value that would be an equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `NSSearchPathDirectory` option for `~/Library/Logs` in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-DontLinkElementID_22), so you have to use `NSLibraryDirectory` and build the rest up yourself:

```
NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory 
                                                       inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *logsURL = [[URLs lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs"];
NSString *logsPath = [libraryURL path];
```

Comment: I had thought about that, but in that case I'd cling to the deprecated API as long as it works, rather than relying on assumption (that they won't rename that folder or that it has the same name on systems in other languages).

Comment: Ok, my bad ... this seems really to be the way to do this (this answer got the blessing from Eric Schlegl @ Apple)